# WPF: animate a custom dependency property?

Tags: wpf, animation, dependency-properties

Let's say that I've defined a dependency like this:

```
     public class MySampleClass
    {public static DependencyProperty MyDoubleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyDouble", typeof(double), typeof(MySampleClass));
    public double MyDouble
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(MyDoubleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyDoubleProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to apply a DoubleAnimation to this value. How can I do this? Always before, I've used DoubleAnimations by calling the BeginAnimation method of a UIElement.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use a DoubleAnimation on a class that doesn't inherit from UIElement?  If not, you should at least inherit from Animatable, or some other base class which also supports BeginAnimation.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working.  I also had to override CreateInstanceCore(), for the record.